# Learning Clojure: recursion for Hidden Markov Model

Tags: recursion, clojure, hidden-markov-models

I'm learning Clojure and started by copying the functionality of a Python program that would create genomic sequences by following an (extremely simple) Hidden Markov model.

In the beginning I stuck with my known way of serial programming and used the *def* keyword a lot, thus solving the problem with tons of side effects, kicking almost every concept of Clojure right in the butt. (although it worked as supposed)

Then I tried to convert it to a more functional way, using *loop*, *recur*, *atom* and so on. Now when I run I get an ArityException, but I can't read the error message in a way that shows me even which function throws it.

```
(defn create-model [name pA pC pG pT pSwitch]
; converts propabilities to cumulative prop's and returns a char
  (with-meta
    (fn []
      (let [x (rand)]
        (if (<= x pA)
          \A
          (if (<= x (+ pA pC))
            \C
            (if (<= x (+ pA pC pG))
              \G
              \T)))))                   ; the function object
    {:p-switch pSwitch :name name}))    ; the metadata, used to change model


(defn create-genome [n]
; adds random chars from a model to a string and switches models randomly
  (let [models [(create-model "std" 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.02) ; standard model, equal props
                (create-model "cpg" 0.1 0.4 0.4 0.1 0.04)]    ; cpg model
        islands (atom 0)                 ; island counter
        m (atom 0)]                      ; model index
    (loop [result (str)]
      (let [model (nth models @m)]
        (when (< (rand) (:p-switch (meta model))) ; random says "switch model!"
;          (swap! m #(mod (inc @m) 2))   ; swap model used in next iteration     
          (swap! m #(mod (inc %) 2))     ; EDIT: correction
          (if (= @m 1)                   ; on switch to model 1, increase island counter
;            (swap! islands #(inc @islands)))) ; EDIT: my try, with error
            (swap! islands inc)))) ;             EDIT: correction
        (if (< (count result) n)         ; repeat until result reaches length n
          (recur (format "%s%c" result (model)))
          result)))))
```

Running it works, but calling *(create-genome 1000)* leads to

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: user/create-genome/fn--772  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

My questions:

- (obviously) what am I doing wrong?
- how exactly do I have to understand the error message?

Information I'd be glad to receive

- how can the code be improved (in a way a clojure-newb can understand)? Also different paradigms - I'm grateful for suggestions.
- Why do I need to put pound-signs # before the forms I use in changing the atoms' states? I saw this in an example, the function wouldn't evaluate without it, but I don't understand :)

Comment: In situations like this, put this in a .clj file and compile it, then when you run it and it throws, it will tell you which line is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's a long shot, but it looks like your atom-updating functions:

```
#(mod (inc @m) 2)
```

and

```
#(inc @islands)
```

are of 0-arity, and they should be of arity at least 1.

This leads to the answer to your last question: the `#(body)` form is a shortcut for `(fn [...] (body))`. So it creates an anonymous function. 
Now the trick is that if `body` contains `%` or `%x` where x is a number, the position where it appears will be substituted for the referece to the created function's argument number `x` (or the first argument if it's only `%`).

In your case that `body` doesn't contain references to the function arguments, so `#()` creates an anonymous function that takes no arguments, which is not what `swap!` expects.

So swap tries to pass an argument to something that doesn't expect it and boom!, you get an ArityException.

What you really needed in those cases was:

```
(swap! m #(mod (inc %) 2)) ; will swap value of m to (mod (inc current-value-of-m) 2) internally
```

and

```
(swap! islands inc) ; will swap value of islands to (inc current-value-of-islands) internally
```

respectively

Comment: Ah, perfect! The documentation of _swap!_ was a bit ambiguous to me, but your explanation that it takes an argument and applies it to the next argument made it clear. Also, your suggestion fixed the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for ways to improve, here's one approach I often find myself going to : Can I abstract this `loop` into a higher order pattern?

In this case, your loop is picking characters at random - this can be modelled as calling a fn of no arguments that returns a character - and then accumulating them together until it has enough of them. This fits very naturally into [`repeatedly`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/repeatedly/), which takes functions like that and makes lazy sequences of their results to whatever length you want.

Then, because you have the entire sequence of characters all together, you can join them into a string a little more efficiently than repeated `format`s - `clojure.string/join` should fit nicely, or you could `apply` `str` over it.

Here's my attempt at such a code shape - I tried to also make it fairly data-driven and that may have resulted in it being a bit arcane, so bear with me:

```
(defn make-generator 
  "Takes a probability distribution, in the form of a map 
  from values to the desired likelihood of that value appearing in the output.
  Normalizes the probabilities and returns a nullary producer fn with that distribution."
  [p-distribution]  
  (let[sum-probs (reduce + (vals p-distribution))
       normalized (reduce #(update-in %1 [%2] / sum-probs) p-distribution (keys p-distribution) )]
      (fn [] (reduce 
              #(if (< %1 (val %2)) (reduced (key %2)) (- %1 (val %2))) 
              (rand) 
              normalized))))

(defn markov-chain 
  "Takes a series of states, returns a producer fn.
  Each call, the process changes to the next state in the series with probability :p-switch,
  and produces a value from the :producer of the current state."
  [states]
  (let[cur-state (atom (first states))
       next-states (atom (cycle states))]
    (fn [] 
      (when (< (rand) (:p-switch @cur-state))
        (reset! cur-state (first @next-states))
        (swap! next-states rest))
      ((:producer @cur-state)))))


(def my-states [{:p-switch 0.02 :producer (make-generator {\A 1 \C 1 \G 1 \T 1})  :name "std"}
                {:p-switch 0.04 :producer (make-generator {\A 1 \C 4 \G 4 \T 1})  :name "cpg"}])


(defn create-genome [n]
  (->> my-states
       markov-chain
       (repeatedly n)
       clojure.string/join))
```

To hopefully explain a little of the complexity:

- The `let` in `make-generator` is just making sure the probabilities sum to 1.
- `make-generator` makes heavy use of another higher-order looping pattern, namely `reduce`. This essentially takes a function of 2 values and threads a collection through it. `(reduce + [4 5 2 9])` is like (((4 + 5) + 2) + 9). I chiefly use it to do a similar thing to your nested `if`s in `create-model`, but without naming how many values are in the probability distribution.
- `markov-chain` makes two atoms, `cur-state` to hold the current state and `next-states`, which holds an infinite sequence (from `cycle`) of the next states to switch to. This is to work like your `m`  and `models`, but for arbitrary numbers of states.
- I then use `when` to check if the random state switch should occur, and if it does perform the two side effects I need to keep the state atoms up to date. Then I just call the :producer of @cur-state with no arguments and return that.

Now obviously, you don't have to do this exactly this way, but looking for those patterns certainly does tend to help me.
If you want to go even more functional, you could also consider moving to a design where your generators take a state (with seeded random number generator) and return a value plus a new state. This "state monad" approach would make it possible to be fully declarative, which this design isn't.

Comment: An interesting approach. It is astounding, how easy your code can be understood (I already knew reductions from programming multiprocessor systems and lazy sequences from Python). I knew that my string reformatting was eating up time, but it seemed to be the simplest way ;-) Just two questions: Won't creating and cycling infinite sequences be slower than cycling array indices? _(mod (inc m) (count states))_ would do the same for arbitrary number of functions I think... And what does the **->>** do? I know **->** would chain the calls, but haven't found this one yet.

Comment: Quite possible, I haven't exactly tested it. It made sense at the time, but at that point I had kinda forgotten about the mod approach.
Another potential advantage of the store-a-mutable-index approach is that you could make a more general Markov process where each state can have individual probabilities of moving to each other state - and you can make those too with `make-generator`.

Comment: `->` and `->>` are kinda sibling macros, sometimes pronounced/referred to as "thread-first" and "thread-last". They both take two or more forms and insert each one into the next form, but in different positions. With `(-> a (b c))`, `a` is inserted as the first argument to `b` (i.e. the expansion is `(b a c)`, while with `(->> a (b c) )` it is the last argument (i.e. the expansion is `(b c a)`).

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake has to do with what you asked about the hashtag macro `#`.

`#(+ %1 %2)` is shorthand for `(fn [x y] (+ x y))`. It can be without arguments too: `#(+ 1 1)`. That's how you are using it. The error you are getting is because [`swap!`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap!) needs a function that accepts a parameter. What it does is pass the atom's current value to your function. If you don't care about its state, use [`reset!`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reset!): `(reset! an-atom (+ 1 1))`. That will fix your error.

Correction:

I just took a second look at your code and realised that you are actually using working on the atoms' states. So what you want to do is this:

`(swap! m #(mod (inc %) 2))` instead of `(swap! m #(mod (inc @m) 2))`.

As far as style goes, you are doing good. I write my functions differently every day of the week, so maybe I'm not one to give advice on that.

Comment: So basically you were a bit slower than soulcheck, giving the same answer, together with an explanation that fills a tiny gap - so your two answers combined make it perfect. Thanks.